# Can i save data to csv file using ec4p controller?

Tags: plc, codesys

I want to save some data to csv file using eaton ec4p controller. I found tutorials that i can do this by using syslibfile library but i can't find it in my libraries. Is it possible that this controller doesn't have this library and can't write data?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try **EC_File.lib** library? I found this definition:

> Data access on the memory card Functions such as FileOpen or FileRead allow you to access the files of the memory card from the user program. These functions are provided in the library EC_File.lib and are described in the Function Blocks manual (MN05010002Z-EN; previously AWB2786-1456GB).

[MN05003003Z_EN - User Manual for Eaton EasyControl EC4-200](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/technicaldocumentation/mn/MN05003003Z_EN.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the library you are looking for is [SysFile](https://help.codesys.com/webapp/idx-SysFile-lib;product=SysFile;version=3.5.17.0) (or SysFile23 for CODESYS 2)